# custom email verification template

Tags: django, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I am using dj rest auth for authentication and i need to override email verification template with my custom html , according to [documantion](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-email), i added these files to account/email directory:

```
account/email/email_confirmation_signup_subject.txt
account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.txt
account/email/email_confirmation_subject.txt
account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt
account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.html
account/email/email_confirmation_message.html
```

and i put the custom html codes in email_confirmation_message.html file , but still i get the default html template in email , is there any step i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside `templates` folder:

```
templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.html
```

I guess that your `TEMPLATE > DIRS` is like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

Comment: I moved the html templates to template/account/email/ instead of template/email/ and it worked!tnx